# Windows Media Center won't reset display to Letterbox aspect ratio

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-center, aspect-ratio

I have long had WMC under WIN7, which I use to set & record off-air broadcasts using the standard WMC input/dialog box, in letterbox format (I don't play programmes on the PC).

After solving some seemingly unrelated PC problems my WMC input/dialog screen had changed from its usual, non-maximised, letterbox aspect ratio (16:10?) to a 4:3 AR.

I've worked through all the WMC Settings to try to regain the letterbox AR, including "Configure Your TV or Monitor", with no luck - the WMC dialog box remains stubbornly 4:3.

I should add that I have dual screens, with the master being 4:3 and the secondary being 16:10 (1680*1050). I've tried the Configure process on both screens, with and without setting it in full screen mode during the configure process.

Can anyone please advise me what else I might try - I know it's possible because it's always been letterbox till now, but not how it got set up in this way originally.

(The reason I prefer the widescreen display is that it shows a longer visual sequence of potential programme settings, and I find it quicker to choose and set the many programmes I record.)

Thank you for any thoughts

Comment: I too have had this problem.  Sometimes I need to shut down the HDMI source and turn it back on or unplug/replug.. then it works right again.  I don't have a solution but am telling you that you aren't alone.. and I have been dealing with this bug since Windows 7 was released.  I think it is probably my receiver but I am still unsure.

Comment: Oh.. also.. I get a sneaking suspicion that it is related to power management somehow.  I have 0% proof of this.

Comment: That might make sense - my seemingly unrelated PC problem involved frequent freezes which I associated with a large Excel .xlsb file, which I've since rebuilt by leaving out the first few years'-worth of data. I'll try some fiddling with powermgt. Again thanks.

Comment: Tried unplugging, different power options...No luck so far.

Comment: @Señor CMasMas ANSWER! Found it in Related question 27222, answer (by greyDrifter in 2009), sitting in front of us at top right of this screen!): CTRL+DRAG the screen. Curiously, it didn't show up when I was drafting the question - maybe my topic list wasn't close enough to the existing answer – iSeeker 10 mins ago